# Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '0.0.0.0:8000'. You may need to add '0.0.0.0' to ALLOWED_HOSTS

Tags: python, django

Django does not seem to find my host `0.0.0.0`

I have already added "0.0.0.0" to my ALLOWED_HOSTS. In fact, if I `print(ALLOWED_HOSTS)` I get 
`['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '0.0.0.0', '[::1]']`. I am working in docker. Is there anything I am overlooking?

**.env.dev**

```
DEBUG=1
SECRET_KEY=foo
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 0.0.0.0 [::1]
SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
SQL_DATABASE=xxxx
SQL_USER=xxxx
SQL_PASSWORD=xxxx
SQL_HOST=db
SQL_PORT=5432
DATABASE=postgres
```

**env_settings.py**

```
import os

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
# DEBUG = True
DEBUG = int(os.environ.get("DEBUG", default=0))

ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.environ.get("DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS").split(" ")

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

**settings.py**

```
from core.env_settings import *

print(ALLOWED_HOSTS)

"""
print(ALLOWED_HOSTS) returns ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '0.0.0.0', '[::1]']
"""
```

NB: I have carefully reviewed all similar questions posted here and there's none with this specific problem.

Comment: Try adding `*` to allowed host

Comment: Did you try only having `0.0.0.0` in allowed host? It's usually a wildcard ip so having more then just the wildcard might be confusing it.

Comment: @MuhammedSidan it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @Serdalis I just did and the error still persists.

Comment: It might be doing an import all from settings.py so try doing `ALLOWED_HOSTS = env_settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS` and see if that works for you.

Comment: You need to set your allowed hosts to your ip address - Since you are using docker it's probably on the 172.17.x.y range - Set your allowed hosts to ["*"] and check that that works?

Answer (score 16):

I just added the ip in `ALLOWED_HOSTS` property in the file <your_app_path>/`settings.py`.

e.g.

```
...
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0']
...
```

And it worked fine.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at settings.py and fill the ALLOWED_HOSTS as follows.
For local host:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["0.0.0.0"]
```

OR you can do

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

in **settings.py**,
change 
`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`
this work for me,
`*`represent the all the ports can have access to the site

Comment: Your answer is incorrect, please read the docs! Also, using the wildcard **['*']** is not best practice especially if someone is DEPLOYING their app.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Docker you'll have to rebuild your container.

Considering you have already added your host on your config file (`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0']`), you just have to run:

```
docker-compose down 

docker-compose build

docker-compose up
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.environ.get('DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS', '*').split()
```

I'm just added `split()` because without `split()` it just `localhost 127.0.0.1 0.0.0.0 [::1]` for django need the `list`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find your device ip address from where you are running the django app.

[How to find the local ip address](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-find-your-local-and-external-ip-address-5833108)

To use django on local network 
Run command 
    python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

To run on other device connected to same local network you have to type ip address of your server device from where you are running django app.

192.168.1.1:8000/   # this is just dummy example.

Its should work as far both devices are connected to same network. And firewall is allowed.